# Pin button ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, scroll, sticky

Help me. I need to make a button that does not move along with scrolling the page

1. It can be a button fixed on the page and
2. It can be a sticky button
3. it can be a popup button

Comment: Could you please share, what you have tried.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/96v04jy3y?file=/src/index.js) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

are you using `position: sticky` and are you giving it a `top` or `bottom` value? Without top or bottom it won't just work.
Have you checked if you browser does support `position: sticky`? That could be the cause as well. If your browser doesn't support it you might need to implement some javascript fallback

I have put together very recently an article on medium that you can check [here](https://dioxmio.medium.com/sticky-done-the-right-way-880af0122a71) if you want to know the insights of it and some examples that might figure out what's wrong